# How would I call this in <php> tags?

Tags: javascript, php

I understand that I might not be too specific in what I want, but I'll try to explain myself as good as I can.

I want to monetize my website, and I'm pretty new to web development.
I want everyone except chosen people, to get ads displayed.
I have setup mysql accounts etc. and I am trying to detect what rank a session is.
What I do atm., is inside of php tags, I get the session, and do

```
if($_SESSION['category'] == "3"){
```

I am just wondering, how I would be able to add this code, inside of the brackets of above code.
I've tried echo 'CODE';
but I couldn't get it to work.
I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Code I want run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
(function() {
    var configuration = {
    "token": "NOT SURE I CAN SHARE THIS",
    "excludeDomains": [
        "NONE"
    ],
    "capping": {
        "limit": 5,
        "timeout": 24
    },
    "entryScript": {
        "type": "timeout",
        "timeout": 3000,
        "capping": {
            "limit": 5,
            "timeout": 24
        }
    },
    "exitScript": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "popUnder": {
        "enabled": true
    }
};
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = '//cdn.shorte.st/link-converter.min.js';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {var rs = this.readyState; if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded') return; shortestMonetization(configuration);};
    var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
})();
//]]></script>
```

What I've tried

```
if ($_SESSION['category' == "3" {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    (function() {
        var configuration = {
        "token": "NOT SURE I CAN SHARE THIS",
        "excludeDomains": [
            "NONE"
        ],
        "capping": {
            "limit": 5,
            "timeout": 24
        },
        "entryScript": {
            "type": "timeout",
            "timeout": 3000,
            "capping": {
                "limit": 5,
                "timeout": 24
            }
        },
        "exitScript": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "popUnder": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    };
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = '//cdn.shorte.st/link-converter.min.js';
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {var rs = this.readyState; if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded') return; shortestMonetization(configuration);};
        var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
    })();
    //]]></script>   ';
}
```

Comment: `if($_SESSION['category'] == "3"){ include 'script.js'; }`

Comment: Why are you using php to write stuff at all. Just break out of php mode (`?>`) and write whatever you want.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to web development. I want it to check if the user is in category 3, and if so, run the JavaScript code. However, I can't make this work outside of php mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can intermingle PHP with HTML, javascript even CSS.. Use the opening and closing PHP tag

```
<?php
 ....  some php script 
if($_SESSION['category'] == "3"){  
// exit PHP to output javascript
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
(function() {
    var configuration = {
    "token": "NOT SURE I CAN SHARE THIS",
    "excludeDomains": [
        "NONE"
    ],
    . . . . snipped for brevity
//]]></script>  
<h1>some plain HTML</h1> <p>Using php short tag is handy
to print out PHP vars </p> &copy;<?=date("Y")?>

<?php // back to PHP mode
 echo 'pretty cool';
// and out again
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am concerned you want to show some add to people except some people wo don't want to see the adds. I suggest you to store your javascript code in .js file and than call it by php. Actually it is not a calling like require or include. You need to print just the text below, of course replacing the full path/file_name.js name of your file.

```
<?php
   echo "<script type="text/javascript" src="path/file_name.js"></script>";
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php 
   if ($_SESSION['category'] == "3" {
        echo "<script type="text/javascript" src="path/file_name.js"></script>";
   }
?>
```

Aim of doing this is to get more readale, understandable, managale code.